# pushViewController not work in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, pushviewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I add button to view by this code:

```
btnMarkerInfo.setImage(imgInfo, for: .normal)
btnMarkerInfo.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
btnMarkerInfo.frame = CGRect(x: w, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-70-56, width: 56, height: 56)
btnMarkerInfo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(vcMain.markerDidTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
btnMarkerInfo.isHidden = true
btnMarkerInfo.alpha = 0
self.view.addSubview(btnMarkerInfo)
```

markerDidTap() is here:

```
func markerDidTap(_ sender: UIButton){
    let vcPointTitles = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vcPointTitles") as! vcPointTitles
    vcPointTitles.pointId = sender.tag
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcPointTitles, animated: false)
}
```

when user tap on this button function `markerDidTap` run and `vcPointTitles` must be show, function execute but vcPointTitles not show.
class and storyBoardId set like as below:
[image: viewcontroller class and info]
vcPointTitles define as below:

```
class vcPointTitles: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { .... }
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: Why have you put a iAtlas in Module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, although it's coming late, but this can be of help to others facing such

```
func markerDidTap(_ sender: UIButton){
   let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let vcPointTitles = 
       storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vcPointTitles") as! 
       VCPointTitlesViewController
    vcPointTitles.pointId = sender.tag

   self.present(vcPointTitles, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You are not pushing ViewController inside NavigationController - instead you are presenting it.